# The scanf function is accepting values infinately

Tags: c, scanf, infinite-loop

---

```
int n;
int a[maxsize];
int b[maxsize];
int c[maxsize];
int i;
printf("enter number of  elements(disks)\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("enter the elements in ascending  order\n");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{   
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
}
```

This works fine at times, but most of the times this piece of code is going into infinite loop,the  'scanf' in the loop is accepting values infinitely,i tried using the function (fflush) to clear the buffer contents,but still its not working, someone please help me out!! and please explain why !!

Comment: "This works fine at times, but most of the times" hmm.. it might depend on your pc mood..right!

Comment: When does it fail? When the first input isn't a decimal number? You should check that by testing the return value from `scanf`.

Comment: @JerryGoyal it's the input that can make this happen.

Comment: @iharob i meant op should specify the "inputs" for which problem causes

Comment: what's this code surrounded with? as it is it can't enter an infinite loop, it will only loop 10 times, assuming `n` is an integer less than the array's size

Comment: why is it actually going into infinate loop ?? @iharob

Comment: It's not an infinite loop, it's impossible. It's expecting some input that you are not giving.

Comment: Please Mothi Mohammed could you give an example of inputs that make the code to enter an infinite loop ?

Comment: I gave n = 6 ..... then I gave all integer values like 1,2,3,4,5,6.... it keeps on accepting values !!! @iharob

Answer (score 1):

The code posted cannot enter an infinite loop, it's probable that the `scanf()` function is blocking until you input something like a <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> to end the input stream or maybe another integer, the problem is that you are handling the input in a very dangerous way because you are not checking for errors at all, what might do what you exactly want is this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define clearstdin() do {int chr; while (((chr = getchar()) != EOF) && (chr != '\n')); } while (0)
#define SOMELARGESIZE 1024

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int index;
    unsigned int size;
    int          result;

    fprintf(stderr, "input the desired array size: ");
    while (((result = scanf("%u", &size)) != 1) && (result != EOF))
     {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input, try again\n");
        clearstdin();
     }
    if (result == EOF)
     {
        fprintf(stderr, "EOF recieved, ending the program\n");
        return -1;
     }
    if (size < SOMELARGESIZE)
     {
        int array[size];

        for (index = 0 ; index < size ; index++)
         {
            fprintf(stderr, "input an integer: ");
            if (((result = scanf("%d", &array[index])) == 1) && (result != EOF))
                fprintf(stdout, "\tarray[%d] = %d\n", index, array[index]);
            else if (result == EOF)
             {
                fprintf(stderr, "EOF recieved, ending the program\n");
                return -1;
             }
            else
             {
                fprintf(stderr, "invalid input, try again\n");
                index -= 1;
             }
            clearstdin();
         }
     }
    else
     {
        fprintf(stderr, "sorry, you requested a very large array\n");
        return -1;
     }
    return 0;
}
```

the only problem with the program above, is that if you input any white space character while `scanf()` is wating for input it will do nothing, until valid or invalid input but specifically non-white-space input is entered.

Comment: Yes. But not related here. `%d` can skip any number of white spaces.

Comment: OP is entering integer

Comment: This wouldn't cause an infinite loop either.

Comment: `((result = scanf("%d", &array[index])) == 1) && (result != EOF)` is strange.  If the first half is true, then the 2nd half is also true.  If the first half is false, the 2nd half is not evaluated.  Suggest simply `(result = scanf("%d", &array[index])) == 1 `

Answer (score 1):

scanf will return the number of items successfully scanned.
If scanf does not return 1, a character is read and scanf tries again.
`scanf ( "%*[^0-9\n]");` will read and discard any characters that are NOT numbers or a newline.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 10

int main()
{
    int i;
    int n;
    int a[SIZE];
    printf("enter number of elements(disks) 0-%d\n", SIZE - 1);
    while ( scanf("%d",&n) != 1 || n >= SIZE) {
        scanf ( "%*[^0-9\n]");
        printf ( "problem with input, try again\n");
    }
    printf("number was %d\n", n);
    printf("enter the elements in ascending  order\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        while ( scanf("%d",&a[i]) != 1) {
            scanf ( "%*[^-0-9\n]");//[^-0-9\n] characters NOT digit, newline or minus
            printf ( "problem with input, try again\n");
        }
        printf("number for a[%d] was %d\n", i, a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just one thing that bothers me, you don't check `n < sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])` which would lead to undefined behavior, the rest is really nice, +1. And also, notify the user about invalid input, it would be confusing to just ask again for input.